# NumPy - What is the difference between frombuffer and fromstring?

Tags: python, numpy

They appear to give the same result to me:

```
In [32]: s
Out[32]: '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x15\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

In [27]: np.frombuffer(s, dtype="int8")
Out[27]:
array([ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
    0,  0,  0, 21,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
    0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
    0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0], dtype=int8)

In [28]: np.fromstring(s, dtype="int8")
Out[28]:
array([ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
    0,  0,  0, 21,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
    0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
    0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0], dtype=int8)

In [33]: b = buffer(s)

In [34]: b
Out[34]: <read-only buffer for 0x035F8020, size -1, offset 0 at 0x036F13A0>

In [35]: np.fromstring(b, dtype="int8")
Out[35]:
array([ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
    0,  0,  0, 21,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
    0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
    0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0], dtype=int8)

In [36]: np.frombuffer(b, dtype="int8")
Out[36]:
array([ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
    0,  0,  0, 21,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
    0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
    0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0], dtype=int8)
```

When should one be used vs. the other?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? `frombuffer` creates a 1d array from a buffer-object and `fromstring` creates a 1d array from a binary or string representation.

Comment: Please edit in what `s` is.

Comment: Whether s is a string of bytes or a buffer doesn't matter in my simple example.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

From a practical standpoint, the difference is that:

```
x = np.fromstring(s, dtype='int8')
```

Will make a copy of the string in memory, while:

```
x = np.frombuffer(s, dtype='int8')
```

or

```
x = np.frombuffer(buffer(s), dtype='int8')
```

Will use the memory buffer of the string directly and won't use any* additional memory.  Using `frombuffer` will also result in a read-only array if the input to `buffer` is a string, as strings are immutable in python.

(*Neglecting a few bytes of memory used for an additional python `ndarray` object -- The underlying memory for the data will be shared.)

---

If you're not familiar with [`buffer` objects (`memoryview` in python3.x)](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/buffer.html), they're essentially a way for C-level libraries to expose a block of memory for use in python.  It's basically a python interface for managed access to raw memory.

If you were working with something that exposed the buffer interface, then you'd probably want to use `frombuffer`.  (Python 2.x strings and python 3.x `bytes` expose the buffer interface, but you'll get a read-only array, as python strings are immutable.)

Otherwise, use `fromstring` to create a numpy array from a string.  (Unless you know what you're doing, and want to tightly control memory use, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the background info on buffer objects.

Comment: @joe-kington Are you sure that np.frombuffer() doesn't make a copy of the buffer? If I run `buffer(np.frombuffer(buffer(s), dtype='int8'))` repeatedly, I get a new buffer location each time, and it's always different from `buffer(s)`.

Comment: @mfripp - You're getting new objects (e.g. a new ndarray each time), but they reference the same memory.  If you'd like to verify this, try using something that's mutable (e.g. an `array.array`) instead of a string and modify the contents. You'll see all of the numpy views and the buffers change.

Comment: @JoeKington, thanks. I experimented a little using `multiprocessing.Array` as the buffer and found they used the same memory. The string representation of the buffer object seems to be misleading; maybe it shows the location of the variable rather than the underlying buffer. A better way to check seems to be `id(buffer[0])`.

Comment: Conversely to the question of @MatthiasFripp, are you sure that `np.fromstring()` *does* make a copy of the data? According to the documentation, "*Deprecated since version 1.14:* If this argument [`sep`] is not provided, `fromstring` falls back on the behaviour of `frombuffer` after encoding unicode string inputs as either utf-8 (python 3), or the default encoding (python 2)." This suggests that the functions are identical if `sep` is not supplied.

Comment: @ArthurTacca - Things have changed quite a bit since this answer was written.  However, it still makes a copy -- note that you get a mutable array as a result (and changing it does not change the string/bytes).  If it didn't make a copy, the resulting array wouldn't be mutable (no copy-on-write possible with the semantics numpy uses here).

Comment: Interesting, thanks. As other evidence, I notice that `x.base` returns the original bytes object (or Python [`array` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html)) when you use `frombuffer()`, but returns `None` if you use `fromstring()`.

Comment: If I use in raspberry python3 np.frombuffer method, because I get deprecation warning from np.fromstring-method, my python application gets killed after random time. Everything can work fine hours, but not tents of hours. No trace is got, python process is just killed. If I change back app to use np.fromstring-method, everything works fine again for days. Seems that np.frombuffer cab be danger to use, even if it is probable more efficient and use less memory.