# numpy frombuffer - AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__buffer__'

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Python Version: 3.5.2
Numpy Version : 1.12.1

Error:

```
import numpy as np
s = 'Hello World'
np.frombuffer(s, dtype='S1')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__buffer__'
```

Things Tried:

> 1. Tried Online Ideone compiler, got same error in Python3.xx.
> 2. Referred [scipy faqs](https://www.scipy.org/scipylib/faq.html#do-numpy-and-scipy-support-python-3-x) for numpy and python compatible version, which states "NumPy support the Python 2.x series, (versions 2.6 and
>      2.7), as well as Python 3.2 and newer. The first release of NumPy to support Python 3 was NumPy 1.5.0."

Can't figure out the issue, tried stackoverflow for same issue but nothing found, may be i had missed it.
Any suggestions or leads on why the error and how to resolve it in python3.xx.

Comment: So at first i was like oh.. it's a simple Dtype error. then i tried it, then i tried harder. Now i have anxiety.

Comment: A string isn't a buffer, especially not in py3, where strings are unicode. What array do you want? Why are you using `frombuffer`?  That's not a beginners tool.

Comment: `frombuffer` docs has an example like this, but it needs to be refined for py3 use.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22236749 is the only related SO question, indicating how rare and specialized `frombuffer` is.  Creating `s` as a bytestring might work.  I can't test from here.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks for your precious comments and link. Beginners usually starts with documentation which is the way i went in order to understand the frombuffer and become more knowledgeable on the subject.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In a PY3 session:

```
In [62]: np.frombuffer('hello world')
...
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__buffer__'
In [63]: np.frombuffer(b'hello world')
...
ValueError: buffer size must be a multiple of element size
In [64]: np.frombuffer(b'hello world',dtype='S1')
Out[64]: 
array([b'h', b'e', b'l', b'l', b'o', b' ', b'w', b'o', b'r', b'l', b'd'],  dtype='|S1')
```

In PY3, the default string type is unicode.  The `b` is used to create and display bytestrings.

The `np.frombuffer` docs should be updated to reflect the difference.  The `'hello world'` example only works with PY2 or with PY3 bytestrings.

As I noted in the comments, there are few SO questions regarding `frombuffer`, indicating that it is rarely used.  `np.array` is by far the most common way of making an array, even from strings:

```
In [80]: np.array('hello')
Out[80]: 
array('hello', 
      dtype='<U5')
```

or use `list` to split the string into characters:

```
In [81]: np.array(list('hello'))
Out[81]: 
array(['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'], 
      dtype='<U1')

In [82]: np.array(b'hello')
Out[82]: 
array(b'hello', 
      dtype='|S5')
In [83]: np.array(list(b'hello'))
Out[83]: array([104, 101, 108, 108, 111])

In [85]: np.fromiter('hello','S1')
Out[85]: 
array([b'h', b'e', b'l', b'l', b'o'], 
      dtype='|S1')
In [86]: np.fromiter('hello','U1')
Out[86]: 
array(['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'], 
      dtype='<U1')*
```

I created a bug issue: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8933