# Inverse of numpy.recarray.tobytes

Tags: python, numpy

What's the inverse to [`numpy.recarray.tobytes`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.recarray.tobytes.html)?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.array([(28483,27759)],dtype=[('x','<u2'),('y','<u2')])
>>> A.tobytes()
'Cool'
```

Here `A` is a 4-byte structured array, and `tobytes` lets me serialize it in binary form. How can I take a binary string of the proper size and deserialize it given a `dtype` object?

Comment: Oh. sounds like an answer....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you want [`frombuffer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html), which interprets a bytestring (or, more generally, any Python object that supports the [buffer protocol](https://docs.python.org/3.6/c-api/buffer.html)) as an array. By default it assumes a `dtype` of `np.float64`, but you can specify a particular `dtype`, including a structured `dtype`.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.frombuffer(b"Cool", dtype=[('x','<u2'),('y','<u2')])
>>> A
array([(28483, 27759)],
      dtype=[('x', '<u2'), ('y', '<u2')])
```

One quirk of `frombuffer` is that it creates an array that refers directly to the bytes you gave it, rather than copying them. That means that if you've used it on a Python bytestring (for example), the resulting array will be readonly:

```
>>> A["x"] = 23
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: assignment destination is read-only
```

If you want something writable, use [`np.fromstring`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html) instead of `np.frombuffer`:

```
>>> A = np.fromstring(b"Cool", dtype=[('x','<u2'),('y','<u2')])
>>> A["x"] = 23
>>> A
array([(23, 27759)],
      dtype=[('x', '<u2'), ('y', '<u2')])
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22237279/270986) for more information.

If you want a genuine NumPy [record array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.rec.html#record-arrays) (rather than a [structured array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.rec.html#module-numpy.doc.structured_arrays), which is just a regular `ndarray` with structured dtype), you can pass the result to `nd.rec.array`:

```
>>> np.rec.array(A)
rec.array([(28483, 27759)], 
          dtype=[('x', '<u2'), ('y', '<u2')])
```

Record arrays are much like structured arrays, but have their own `ndarray` subclass, and allow retrieval of fields via attribute access:

```
>>> B = np.rec.array(A)
>>> B.x
array([28483], dtype=uint16)
```

Comment: that's it! I kept looking for `frombytes` and finding nothing. Thanks!